# what's wrong with this mysql join?

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

```
SELECT p1.userid, p1.username, p2.lids 
        FROM VB_user p1
        LEFT JOIN AB_judge_perm p2 on p1.userid = p2.userid
        WHERE p1.membergroupids LIKE '".19.",%'
        OR p1.membergroupids LIKE '%,".19."'
        OR p1.membergroupids LIKE '%,".19.",%'
        OR p1.membergroupids = '".19."'
```

I'm thinking `p1.membergroupids` doesn't play well with joins? If I remove the `p1.membergroupids` conditionals, the query works like I wanted to work, exept I want it to only show users that are part of group 19, thus the `LIKE`s. The `p1.membergroupids` is a multivalue attribute.

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work, I mean do you get any specific error?

Comment: you shouldn't put .19 since it can be translated as 0.19. make sure you put a space there

Comment: It's not an error issue, it's that I'm not getting the results I'm suppose to get. The `p1.membergroupid` filters are not getting applied to the results

Comment: @galchen You nailed it! that's was the problem. Damn syntax. Thanks :)

Comment: heh i didn't really think it would be the problem, just thought it was good to mention ;) glad i helped

Comment: I'd say your real problem is that you're using a "multivalue attribute" kludge, use a proper association table and things will be much easier and faster to boot.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @muistooshort you should move your membergroupids to a many-to-many join table and this problem will disappear. Hideously unnormalised structures like this will cause you untold amounts of pain! Create a new join table - member_group(member_id, group_id)

If you insist on using this hideous structure you can replace your mulitple OR conditions with [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) -

```
SELECT p1.userid, p1.username, p2.lids 
FROM VB_user p1
LEFT JOIN AB_judge_perm p2
    ON p1.userid = p2.userid
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(19, p1.membergroupids)
```